# change tag style when Hover on another tag outside parent child, using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this sample code:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="main">Main</li>
    <li class="text">Text</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.main:hover + .text {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Here is the [demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/ZW7dc/)

Now when I Hover on `.main`, Style of `.text` changed.
It's correction.

Now I want have be like this happen for this HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="main">Main</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="text">Text</li>
</ul>
```

I want when I hover on `.main`, The style of `.text` want to change.
I try this CSS code:

```
.main:hover + .text {
    background-color: green;
}
```

But does not work.
How can I do this without use javascript?

Here is the [demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/ZW7dc/1/)

Comment: Unfortunately, what you're wanting to achieve can't be done with CSS—there's no way to select the parent of an element.

Comment: The reason your first example works is that `+` is the adjacent sibling selector.  Assuming this is just a toy example of what you're trying to accomplish, would it be possible to put the classes on the `ul` instead of the `li`?

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no way to select an elements parent (it would of course be an useful feature to select ul < li etc.), it would not work without involving JavaScript.

There may be a solution though: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly2GF/1/)

It's done by using the general sibling selector indicated by a tilde (~):

```
.main:hover ~ ul>.text {
    background-color: green;
}
```

But this solution presumes the elements to have the same parent.

Edit:
The difference between the adjacent sibling selector (+) and the general sibling selector (~) is that the first one just works if in case of a + b b directly follows a within the markup. The second one is less strict.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But the HTML of my example should not have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't target CSS outside the parent scope. This would involve JS.

**jQuery:**

```
var hoverEl = $('.main');
var targetEl = $('.text');

hoverEl.on('mouseenter', function() { 
  targetEl.css({'background-color': 'green'});
});

hoverEl.on('mouseleave', function() { 
  targetEl.css({'background-color': 'none'});
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/ZW7dc/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, but refer to said I don't want to use JS. (also your demo link was incorrect)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. You forgot the JS code, put it in the demo link. Also, in the case of `mouseleave`, the `background-color` property does not take the value of `none` and `background` should be used. All that aside, my goal was to not use js. (: